# Geoip extension not work and found on php info

Tags: php, geoip

I downloaded  the geoip extension from pecl php and inserted in ext file on php 5.3 and edit `php-ini` file and write

```
Extenstion=php_Geoip.DLL
```

and remove `;`

Geoip function still doesn't work.
And in `phpinfo` the Geoip function doesn't appear.
What I must do?

Comment: `Extenstion` is misspelled.

Comment: I re-write Extension=php_Geoip.dll but still not work and still not appear in phpinfo

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure you are using the correct DLL-file. You should check if you are using Thread-Safe / Not-Thread-Safe and x86 or x64 (on PHP 5.3 not needed).

On the `php.ini` file you have to insert the following line:

```
extension=php_geoip.dll
```

Make also sure you insert the DLL-file to the correct directory (PHP extension directory) and editing the correct `php.ini` file (see `Loaded Configuration File` on `phpinfo()`).

**Download for Windows:** http://pecl.php.net/package/geoip/1.1.1/windows

After adding this line to your `php.ini` file and choosing the correct DLL-file you should see the GeoIP information on the `phpinfo` output.

[image]